# Show activity circle before loading webview - Android

Tags: android, webview, android-progressbar

I am using `webview` to show a webpage in my app. The webpage takes about 2-3 seconds to load.
Till the webpage loads, I want to show an activity circle progress bar like the one shown [here](https://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html).
 This is what an activity circle looks like :

[image]

How can I accomplish it?

I searched the web but couldn't find a satisfactory and proper explanation of how it is implemented. Thanks!

WebViewPage.java

```
public class Webpage extends Activity {

WebView web;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_page);

    Intent startwebpage = getIntent();

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: don't call view.loadUrl from shouldOverrideUrlLoading. If you do pages like this: http://jsbin.com/gupug/1/quiet will break your app.

Answer (score 4):

Display `progressBar` in `onPageStarted` method and dismiss it in `onPageFinished`.

```
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;
```

1. Show progressBar in onPageStarted:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        // prepare for a progress bar dialog
           progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
           progressBar.setCancelable(true);
           progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);            
           progressBar.show();
   }
   ```

2.Dismiss it in onPageFinished:

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.dismiss();
    }
```

**EDIT :** Use `ProgressBar` instead of `ProgressDialog`.

1. Use Following code in your layout. 
   Use drawable of your choice for "@drawable/progress"

   ```
    <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:visibility="gone"
       android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress" >
   </ProgressBar>
   ```
2. Inflate it in your activity. Make it visible in onPageStarted and gone in onPageFinished.

   ```
   private ProgressBar prgrsBar;

   @Override
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

       prgrsBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }

    @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPageFinished(view, url);

       prgrsBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
   ```

Comment: I think you got my question wrong! I don't want to show a dialog. I want to show an animating activity circle like the one shown in my question.

Comment: ok, in that case I would suggest you to use Progress bar instead of ProgressDialog. Check edited answer

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
    `ProgressDialog pb = null;`

```
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            // prepare for a progress bar dialog
            if (pb == null) {
                pb = new ProgressDialog(Quiz.this);
                pb.setCancelable(true);
                pb.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                pb.show();
            }
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            pb.dismiss();
        }
```