# Using a spinner in android

Tags: android, spinner

In my android app, I want to show a spinner in my activity when a user clicks login button after entering the details.The spinner should appear only till the login process is validated in the background. After it is done, then the spinner should disappear and the user should be taken to the desired activity.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Show related code, and mention where are you stuck?

Comment: use background AsyncTask and implement progress Dialog on its preExecute method and dismiss it in postExecute method, when background task is completed.

Comment: please refer this link : http://nads-rosun.blogspot.in/2014/01/android-login-application-using.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have trouble finding this because in Android the 'Spinner' name is already taken for another control. What you are looking for is an Activity Circle in the form of a `ProgressBar`. Maybe these SO questions will be of help to you:

[Show activity circle before loading webview - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115800/show-activity-circle-before-loading-webview-android)

[how to show progress bar(circle) in an activity having a listview before loading the listview with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559461/how-to-show-progress-barcircle-in-an-activity-having-a-listview-before-loading)